# No match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'String' and 'void')

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I am querying a webpage that returns a JSON string using a NodeMCU ESP8266 microcontroller. Response from the webpage looks like this:

```
{"1":true,"2":false,"3":false,"4":true,"5":true,"6":false,"7":false,"8":false}
```

The code I am using looks like this:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
String payload = "";
const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";
String url = "example.com/data.json";
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(2000); while (!Serial);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() !=WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  pinMode(D0, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  StaticJsonBuffer<100> jsonBuffer;
  delay(5000);
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(url);
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  Serial.println(http.getString());
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    payload = http.getString();
  }
  http.end();
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(payload);
  Serial.println(payload);
  if(!root.success()) {
    Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
  }
  if(root["1"] == true) {
    Serial.println("true");
  }
  digitalWrite(D0, !digitalRead(D0));
}
```

I believe the reason it fails to parse is that the payload variable ends with a trailing newline character. I then attempted `payload = payload.trim();` but then I get `no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'String' and 'void')` so I tried `payload = payload.replace("\n,"");` same issue, then I tried `payload = String(payload);` again, failure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read [the docs](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/). `trim` and `replace` don't return anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user, please take the [tour]. Also, your kind of question requires a [mcve] to be on topic, please extract that before even asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like someone has said, `trim` and `replace` do not return `String`. It "returns" `void`, the error message is telling you that you're trying to assign a void return to a String. It suffices to put `payload.trim();`. The same goes for `payload.replace("\n","");`

But `payload.trim();` and `payload.replace("\n","");` don't do the same thing. As mentioned in the docs, `trim()` removes trailing and leading whitespaces, while `replace("\n","")` will remove all (and only) newlines in the string, even if it's in the middle.

Whitespace generally refers to space, newline, tabs, and some other miscellaneous characters.